# Gitlab + Jekyll not rendering correctly utf-8 group_by jekyll

Tags: utf-8, jekyll, gitlab, gitlab-ci

Gitlab is not working good with some code that uses UTF-8

Local machine using 3.1.2 renders okay, as Github

Code:

```
{% assign pt_sorted_posts = ptposts | group_by: "tags" | sort: "name" %}
```

The problem:

Tag is

```
"Destino dos Desenhos Animados - 1a. Delegacia da Desenholândia"
```

Into Gitlab it is rendered:

```
Destino dos Desenhos Animados - 1a. Delegacia da Desenhol\u00E2ndia
```

UTF-8 `<meta>` encoding was set

Original Markdown file is UTF-8

Problematic page: http://fabiocosta0305.gitlab.io/personagens/

Github page: http://fabiocosta0305.github.io/personagens/

Comment: Can you provide the `.gitlab-ci.yml` file as well as the `Gemfile` and `Gemfile.lock`?

Comment: https://gitlab.com/fabiocosta0305/fabiocosta0305.gitlab.io/blob/master/.gitlab-ci.yml

Comment: No Gemfile for me... And Gemfile.lock I started to put on .gitignore after some problems in other Gitlab pages

Comment: I'd recommend using a Gemfile instead of manually installing each gem, `gem install jekyll` will just install the latest version of Jekyll, which right now is 3.3.0, so the GitLab site differs from the local site and the GitHub site. See my Jekyll site: https://gitlab.com/connorshea/connorshea.gitlab.io

Comment: Used you Gemfile as reference... And didn't worked...

Comment: you also need to update the .gitlab-ci.yml file to use `bundle install` instead of gem install.

Comment: Okay... I'm mobile now... I'll try

Comment: Tried it... Didn't worked... :(

Answer (score 1):

Did an ugly hack by replacing the \u00AA by the correct character... It worked... But it's really bad!